# How do i load a variable from the ESB registry (in a linux enviornment) using a custom component

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am a new developer in WSO2 ESB. 
I want to create a registry variable that i will be able to use in my custom components, this variable will contain the path of the configuration files i am using (custom.properties).

The reason i am doing that is that in our old linux based wso2 ESB servers we installed the components in our /OPT folder but in newer version the path is not identical. so i need get the relative path of the configuration files (custom.properties) so that the custom components can pull them and find the relative path.

Comment: you could create any registry artifact with GUI. what do you mean by `using custom component` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways to access a registry resource programmatically.

1. With [Registry Service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Accessing+Registry+Remotely+through+API) - This way the registry resource can be accessed as a REST resource via HTTP. The disadvantage is the lower performance and higher latency.
2. With [WSO2 Registry Java API](https://dzone.com/articles/access-wso2-registry) - This is the advanced way to access a Registry resource with direct database calls to the Registry database. This is the standard way used in all WSO2 internal implementations to access a registry resource.